# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass when sending mail, on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass when sending mail, on staging.

NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Has anyone experienced this bug? In the development environment, letters go perfectly

```
21 File "/var/www/vectoring-staging/releases/20140505020949/app/models/feedback.rb" line 11 in deliver
22 File "/var/www/vectoring-staging/releases/20140505020949/app/controllers/feedbacks_controller.rb" line 4 in "createp/controllers/feedbacks_controller.rb" line 4 in create

class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])
    @feedback.deliver if @feedback.valid?
  end
end

class Feedback
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :email, :message
  attr_writer :subject

  validates :message, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, allow_blank: true

  def deliver
    FeedbackMailer.new_feedback(self).deliver
  end

  def subject
    @subject = 'A new feedback' if @subject.blank?
    @subject
  end
end

class FeedbackMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'email'

  def new_feedback(feedback)
    @message = feedback.message
    mail(to: APP_CONFIG.feedback['to_send'], subject: feedback.subject, reply_to: feedback.email)
  end
end
```

Comment: where is the method that you are calling `.split` on?

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: @WaliAli that's it that I never called `split`.

Comment: @YosepKim https://gist.github.com/vadus1/3df79fff1d6570c15c31

Comment: I see what you saying. the method must be coming from one of the gems or maybe is a bug.

Comment: @WaliAli Yes, indeed the cause of the error in `gem 'premailer'`

Comment: I still don't see in the log, where you see the nil error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the paths to the assets (i.e. CSS) in your email are correct (and exist).